Touch blocked on raspberry pi when pressing repeatedly
I have a raspberry pi in kiosk mode connected to a 32 inch touch screen.
When I press quickly for a while the touch screen is blocked and does not allow me to perform any action.
I am trying to change the configuration /boot/config.txt to see if I can avoid this error. I have increased the gpu from 256 to 512MB, the config_hdmi_boost from 4 to 11... and I have not managed to not block it by pressing anywhere on the touch screen hundreds of times.
When the touch screen is blocked I have tried to connect a mouse and a keyboard and it works with them. That is why I think it is the touch screen that is failing.
The file /boot/config.txt is the following:
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
framebuffer_width=1080
framebuffer_height=1920

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
dtparam=spi=off

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

# Automatically load overlays for detected cameras
camera_auto_detect=1

# Automatically load overlays for detected DSI displays
display_auto_detect=1

# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver
#dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

# Disable compensation for displays with overscan
disable_overscan=1

[cm4]
# Enable host mode on the 2711 built-in XHCI USB controller.
# This line should be removed if the legacy DWC2 controller is required
# (e.g. for USB device mode) or if USB support is not required.
otg_mode=1

[all]

[pi4]
# Run as fast as firmware / board allows
arm_boost=1

[all]

disable_splash=1
enable_uart=1
gpu_mem=512
max_usb_current=1
avoid_warnings=1
#hdmi_group=2
#means DMT (Display Monitor Timings; the standard typically used by monitors)
#hdmi_mode=87
# indicates the resolution mode we set before.
hdmi_cvt=1920 1080 60 4 0 0 0
#hdmi_cvt=1280 800 60 4 0 0 0
hdmi_drive=2
#selects the Normal HDMI mode.
config_hdmi_boost=9
display_hdmi_rotate=1
display_lcd_rotate=1

#Muxunav
#hdmi_force_hotplug:0=1
hdmi_force_hotplug:1=1
#hdmi_group:0=1
#hdmi_group:1=1
#hdmi_mode:0=16
#hdmi_mode:1=16

#bueno
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=4

hdmi_group:1=2
hdmi_mode:1=82

My display model is: Data Modul EP320W NDD812 with a resolution of 1920x1080 60HZ
How can I avoid this problem? Any idea why it could be happening?

what does this mean? ... When I press quickly

If I repeatedly tap anywhere on the screen for a while it ends up freezing. It seems like it freezes because it can't process so many taps.
